# Is there a way to listen for non-saved changes of a file?

Tags: ruby, listener

Currently, I am using the ruby Listen gem that listens for file saves in an ongoing manner and then my application can reacts accordingly after a file is saved.  What I would like to do is be able to be updated if a user is updating a file, but not rely on save to get that information.

The use case would be that User X opens a .txt file (which I have predefined) and starts typing in it. With every cursor move, change, keystroke etc I can hear that something has changed and be able to know what the current contents of that .txt file are.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you implementing the editor?

Comment: no... random file that resides in the wild that is edited with anything.

Comment: Consider making a plugin/extension for the editor the user is using, if you have control over that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since most editors *read* the file to memory, and let the user edit it there, the file system has no idea whether any editor is currently editing any file *in memory*...

The only thing the file system 'knows' is when a file is read or written...